# How to register an Office 365 Application in Azure AD automatically using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, office365

For easy deployment, I want to automate app registration process office 365 Azure AD.  Manuel process is complex and time consuming to apply certificates and granting certain permissions on calendar or active directory or Graph.

I want to simplify the whole registration and deployment process so that process goes smoothly.

[manual process link click here](https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/RegisterAnAppInAzure.md)

Comment: ...so what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far. Can also elaborate on why you need to automate this? What situation leads you to having to repeat this often enough for it to be a problem?

Comment: I have automated the Azure-AD application process for application deployment process for non technical persons and it is bit complex to create application, download manifest and assigning 64 bit certificate keys and then upload it to the Azure-AD application. Overall I tried to achieve simplification, error free and faster deployment process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following command to new Microsoft online ServicePrincipal

```
C:\PS>$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
              $cer.Import("C:\temp\myapp.cer")
              $binCert = $cer.GetRawCertData()
              $credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binCert);
              New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames @("MyApp/myApp.com") 
                                       -DisplayName "My Application" 
                                       -Type asymmetric -Value $credValue
```

New service principal object created.

You need to connect to MsolService

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credential
```