# PowerShell script to Automate AAD app and assigning delegated Permissions

Tags: powershell, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

Continue to my [last question how to automate azure AD app creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781260/how-to-register-an-office-365-application-in-azure-ad-automatically-using-powers) 
I could manage to automate AAD creation using PowerShell script, but wanted to go one step ahead and assign permissions to application like MS graph/ Azure AD, office 365  etc [image: e.g. assign or delegate permissions].

I don't find any help on MS. Can anybody give some hint on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions to Other Applications is stored on the Application Object under the property `requiredResourceAccess`.

Here is an example of that property from an app I created. I pulled this from the Application Manifest:

```
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "ba7111b6-5517-4c9a-8f65-68dffe1f44c4",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "76514d0f-b098-4ff1-9606-26ddd811ba05",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "cba73afc-7f69-4d86-8450-4978e04ecd1a",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

You can see that the property is composed of two parts: the App ID of the resource, and the Permission ID exposed on that Resource.

The best thing you can do here is set up an app in your tenant using the UX, and then look at the way that the `requiredResourceAccess` is set.

Then you can use [this PowerShell Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) to update that property in your automated workflow.

`Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <guid> -RequiredResourceAccess <RRAList>`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, is there any documentation available on MSDN for GUID and respective permissions or any mapping table. As we can't guess which GUID is used for what?

Comment: If you look at the Service Principal object in your tenant for the resource you are trying to access, you will get back all the permissions that API exposes in the `OAuth2Permissions` section of the JSON.

Comment: you can also take a look at the Manifest of an existing AAD application. This way you will also be able to find the necessary GUIDs