# how to give grant Permissions for an app in azure ad using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, permissions, automation, azure-active-directory

trying to automate the azure app registration process using powershell

need some help for giving grant permission for an app after assigning api permissions using powershell can anyone help me on this.

and is there any better way to automate azure app reg process other than powershell?

Comment: This document might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduserapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0.

These SO threads may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841968/powershell-script-to-automate-aad-app-and-assigning-delegated-permissions 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346121/powershell-do-grant-permissions-action-on-azure-ad-application-with-powershe.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, 

$req1.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
 $req2.ResourceAppId = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
 Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $newapp.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess @($req1,$req2)

this is what i am look for exactly, i can able to give api permissions by above code using powershell, but once i give api permissions to my app, i need to grant  permissions to the app . so i am look for some help on that, like any powershell script which can do the grant permission to app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
Login-AzureRmAccount

```
function get-azureRMToken() {
    <#
    .Synopsis
     This function gets the access token for the use
    #>
    try {
        $context = Get-AzureRmContext
        $tenantId = $context.Tenant.Id
        $refreshToken = @($context.TokenCache.ReadItems() | where {$_.tenantId -eq $tenantId -and $_.ExpiresOn -gt (Get-Date)})[0].RefreshToken
        $body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6"
        $apiToken = Invoke-RestMethod "https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        return $apiToken.access_token
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Exception.Message=$($_.Exception.Message); ScriptStackTrace=$($_.ScriptStackTrace); Exception.StackTrace=$($_.Exception.StackTrace); FullyQualifiedErrorId=$($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId); Exception.InnerException=$($_.Exception.InnerException)"
    }
}

function grant-aap-required-permission() {
    <#
    .Synopsis
     This function invoke azure rest to grant permission.
     #>
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$azureAppId
    )
    try {
        $token = get-azureRMToken
        $header = @{
            'Authorization'          = 'Bearer ' + $token
            'X-Requested-With'       = 'XMLHttpRequest'
            'x-ms-client-request-id' = [guid]::NewGuid()
            'x-ms-correlation-id'    = [guid]::NewGuid()
        }
        $url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/$azureAppId/Consent?onBehalfOfAll=true"
        Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $url –Headers $header –Method POST -ErrorAction Stop

    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Exception.Message=$($_.Exception.Message); ScriptStackTrace=$($_.ScriptStackTrace); Exception.StackTrace=$($_.Exception.StackTrace); FullyQualifiedErrorId=$($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId); Exception.InnerException=$($_.Exception.InnerException)"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we can now use the Azure CLI in powershell. I can grant permission with a single command.

```
az ad app permission grant –id $appId –api $apiAppId –scope $scope
```

This worked on the Azure Cloud Shell where $appId, $apiAppId, and $scope are regular powershell variables.

The documentation for this command is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_permission_grant

Note that $scope should be the `Value` property from the `Oauth2Permission` you are using.